# Why I'm getting MissingReferenceException exception when starting the coroutine over and over again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateWalls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectToRaise;
    public float duration;
    public Vector3 raiseAmount;
    public bool go = false;
    public Color[] colors = new Color[4];
    public bool randomColors = false;

    private GameObject objtoraise;
    private GameObject[] walls;
    private bool scaleOver = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        Init();

        ColorWalls();

        // The z Axis must be minimum 1 or any value above 0 could be also 0.1f
        // but it's better to keep it minimum as 1 by default.
        if (raiseAmount.z < 1)
        {
            raiseAmount.z = 1f;
        }

        if (go)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(objtoraise, new Vector3(raiseAmount.x, raiseAmount.y,
                raiseAmount.z), duration));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            //if (scaleOver)
            //{
            if (objtoraise != null)
            {
                if (raiseAmount.z < 1)
                {
                    raiseAmount.z = 1f;
                }


                Destroy(objtoraise);

                Init();

                ColorWalls();

                StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(objtoraise, new Vector3(raiseAmount.x, raiseAmount.y,
                    raiseAmount.z), duration));

                scaleOver = false;
                //}
            }
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        objtoraise = Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise);
        objtoraise.name = "Walls";

        walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Wall");
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(GameObject objectToScale, Vector3 scaleTo, float seconds)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingScale = objectToScale.transform.localScale;
        while (elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        objectToScale.transform.localScale = scaleTo;

        scaleOver = true;
    }

    private void ColorWalls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < walls.Length; i++)
        {
            if (randomColors)
            {
                walls[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color
                    = GetRandomColour32();
            }
            else
            {
                walls[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private Color32 GetRandomColour32()
    {
        //using Color32
        return new Color32(
          (byte)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 255), //Red
          (byte)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 255), //Green
          (byte)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 255), //Blue
          255 //Alpha (transparency)
        );
    }
}
```

Inside the Update() when I press the R key it's destroying the Instantiated object and then Instantiate is again and start the coroutine again. The problem is when I press on the R key many times in a row after two times I'm getting MissingReferenceException  exception in the editor :

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
GenerateWalls+d__12.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GenerateWalls.cs:81)

Line 81 is :

```
objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
```

The goal is to be able to generate the walls each time over again when pressing R it should stop the current coroutine and start over.

Maybe the problem is that it's in the middle of the coroutine and because the old coroutine didn't stop yet then the object is missing in the middle because I destroy it?

How then I should do it to be able to press R over and over again and it will start the coroutine over and over? Not to start multiple coroutines but to start each time the coroutine over again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add : StopCoroutine In the Update()

This is not the solution. I thought stopping the coroutine will stop also the while loop inside but it didn't.  It seems that checking for null inside the while loop solved the problem :

```
public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(GameObject objectToScale, Vector3 scaleTo, float seconds)
    {
        if (objectToScale != null)
        {
            float elapsedTime = 0;
            Vector3 startingScale = objectToScale.transform.localScale;
            while (elapsedTime < seconds)
            {
                if (objectToScale == null)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
                    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            objectToScale.transform.localScale = scaleTo;

            scaleOver = true;
        }
    }
```